# Quality of my TIFF file goes down dramatically

Tags: arcmap, geotiff-tiff, image-pyramids, bigtiff, cloud-optimized-geotiff

Every time I upload a TIFF to ArcMap, after I build pyramids (using a nearest neighbor algorithm) the quality of the TIFF file after it is added to ArcMap goes down dramatically. Why?

Comment: Could you add a link to some image that could be used as test data?

Comment: (Pyramids are a downsampled lower-resolution copy of the data) What if you try building more levels using bilinear or cubic convolution?

Comment: Make sure you're not using lossy compression for the pyramids as well (e.g. JPEG)